# Mapping UK counties in Excel maps data vis

Tags: excel, powerbi

I'm trying to use Excel or Power BI (filled maps) to visualise some very basic data.

The problem is not all counties appear when you produce the chart and the counties don't always fill the correct area. If I try and complete a full UK map there are plenty missing as seen in the Google Sheets document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wFZ-SeqdW4EMFzi79oo2Ce5tFPkM_Zvu/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118297193733795523496&rtpof=true&sd=true

Even if trying just to map some of the Midlands/North, it is arguably maps Merseyside and Greater Manchester *incorrectly* and wants other counties to fill in the spaces.

[image]